# Accessing DataGridView thru DataTable

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

There's a simple form with datagridview "dg1" and button "cmdShow".
dg1 isn't connected to any external database and has just 2 columns.

Clicking the button should show the entered data.

Programm execution stops at foreach statement with "System.NullReferenceException".
When checking "dt" in debug mode it's NULL indeed.

Did I forget something or did I misunderstood line with "DataTable dt = dg1.DataSource as DataTable;" ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace test2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
        }

        private void cmdShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string m = "";
            DataTable dt = dg1.DataSource as DataTable;
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)    // error    "System.NullReferenceException" on dt.Rows
            {
                m = m + row.Field<string>(0) + " " + row.Field<string>(1) + "\n";
            }
            MessageBox.Show(m);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what are the values of the Datatable where are you populating the datatable..? also is the datagridview populated at design time..? can you provide more information..? if you want to iterate the datatable.. you need to at least display to us and or show us the `where and how` the DataTabele is being loaded..

Comment: The datagridview ist populated during execution time manually through user. After populating the datagridview I want to process the data in a datatable.

Comment: For iterating the `DataGridView` data, see Monty's answer. For populating a `DataTable`, you'll have to create a new `DataTable` object and populate it using that data.

Comment: @Schnulli, we hope that your issue has been resolved. May I suggest some further reading http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work... regards...

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are trying to set 'dt' to reference dg1.DataSource BUT you are not setting dg1.DataSource to a DataTable anywhere.... I assume that you are simply entering data into the DGV manually, we cant see that bit of your code....

Try this....

```
private void cmdShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string m = "";
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dg1.Rows)    // error    "System.NullReferenceException" on dt.Rows
        {
            m = m + row.Cells[0].Value + " " + row.Cells[1].Value + "\n";
        }
        MessageBox.Show(m);
     }
```

Hope that helps....